# AWS Lambda to AWS Lambda permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-lambda

Trying to use lambda.invoke method from the AWS docs. However I get permission issues when trying to test this.

Could anyway guide me on how to set up these permissions?

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
  region: 'us-west-2' //change to your region
});

lambda.invoke({
  FunctionName: 'lambda_function',
  Payload: JSON.stringify('hello world') // pass params
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    context.done('error', error);
  }
  if(data.Payload){
   context.succeed(data.Payload)
  }
});
```

Using these docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to provide permissions to your caller Lambda function to invoke another function,
Your caller function will need an IAM Policy like -

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Lambda permission",
      "Action": [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:awsRegion:awsAccountId:function:functionName"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you're calling your function from local,
Your AWS Credentials will need the same access